# How do I write variables to a file in scala and then load them back into scala?

Tags: scala, import, io, java.util.scanner

I have a bunch of variables in scala:

```
triangleCount = 2
lives = 5
triangleScore = 1
curPlayer.getX
curPlayer.getY
```

When I press "s" in my match case:

```
case "s" =>
```

I want the variables to be written to an external file.

Then when I press "l" in my match case:

```
case "l" =>
```

I want the variables to be loaded back into my program and replace the default ones.

How would I go about doing this?  I know it has something to do with scala.io.Source or java Scanner but i'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: That is a question with many, many non-trivial answers. Unless your needs are extremely simple (and Chris' answer suffices), you want some sort of serialization / deserialization framework. Many are available. They have not been perfected, alas...

Answer (score 1):

```
case "s" => 
  val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter("myVars")
  pw.println(List(triangleCount, lives, triangleScore, curPlayer.getX, curPlayer.getY).mkString("\t"))
  pw.close

case "l" =>
  val myVarsFromFile = io.Source.fromFile("myVars").getLines.toList
  if (!myVarsFromFile.isEmpty) {
    val toks = myVarsFromFile.head.split("\t")
    var (triangleCount,lives, triangleScore) = (toks(0).toInt, toks(1).toInt, toks(2).toInt)
    curPlayer.setX(toks(3).toDouble)
    curPlayer.setY(toks(4).toDouble)
  }
```